# How can a value be passed directly from a windows application into a field in an open web page?

Tags: windows

I have a problem that I feel is best implimented in a stand alone windows application, but needs to pass data to a web page that is already open.

Is it possible to pass the data directly to the web page?

If so, what is the best way to go about it?

(Its my first question, so go easy on me!)

Comment: I hope you're not writing some kind of spamming program to spam web forms... or something to guess captchas... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be an easy problem to solve, but I *think* it's possible by hosting the web-page in a browser embedded in a .NET application. [This Code-Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx) might help

Also [this article](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000052.html) talks a bit about accessing the DOM through a C# application.

Have you got any requirements on language? And can you add a bit more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve?

EDIT 1: [Watij](http://sourceforge.net/projects/watij/) is a web-application testing framework for Java. You can use it to fill in text-boxes, click buttons etc. I think it might fit your needs and, if it doesn't, it's open-source, so you might be able to hack it to work. There is a whole family of Wati* products - Watin for .NET, Watir for Ruby, etc.

Comment: We need to do some modeling that would work best if graphicly displayed, and we are required to use a fairly restrictive in house framework when building web pages. If we could use a stand alone app and pass various values back to the open web page, it would help avoid the framework problem.

Comment: The app language would probably need to be Java, and for the web unfortunantly we are stuck with the in house xml based frame work.

Answer (score 1):

Getting access to external web pages are not permitted due to security credentials.
But you can open and write to a web page via winInet APIs.
Please go through the article

http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=107